ROS2 - Deterministic - As-fast-as-Possible Bag Replay
I have a question about ros2 bag replay:
Given an bag file that contains a video stream of images, I want to replay the bag file as-fast-as-possible (e.g. by specifying a very high rate parameter).
Then, I have a subscriber node, which subscribes to the image-topic from the bag file and processes the image data in a corresponding callback function. Both (replay and subscriber) are configured with QoS-Setting "RELIABLE". (I also experimented with configuring the subscriber into a single-threaded-node)
The processing of a frame now takes longer than the replay of a frame, so either the buffer will fill up (QoS-Setting: KEEP_ALL or frames are dropped (QoS-Setting: KEEP_Last, Depth=5)
--> I would now like to force the whole chain to run as-fast-as-possible but without dropping frames. Therefor the bag-file replay should only send out new frames, when the subscriber node has processed the frames.
I was hoping that exactly this is achieved by specifing the "--wait-for-all-acked" commandline argument in "ros2 bag play", but according to my own experiments it is not.
--> What am I missing here? Isn't this use-case what the commandline argument is for? When does the subscriber actually acknowledge an incoming message?
--> Can the desired behavior be achieved with ROS2?
Thanks in advance for your feedback!
